# When does Kubernetes automatically re create AWS ELB

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, aws-elb, amazon-eks

I am using `Helm` to deploy a `k8s` cluster onto `AWS EKS`.

My k8s cluster uses:

1. One LoadBalancer service. We explicitly sets this ELB to `AWS Network ELB` using an annotation provided by aws docs.
2. Two ingresses controlled by an `alb-ingress-controller`. When deployed, two `AWS Application ELB`s are created.

My question:

After running `helm upgrade --install --force...` to install the charts for the first time, issuing following `helm upgrade --install --force...`s sometimes result in new `ELB`s being created.

I want to learn more about this behavior between **re deploying k8s resources onto an existing resources** and `ELB` re-creation.

Official documents about when `aws ELB`s are recreated when they're used with `k8s` are most appreciated.

Comment: I'm also wondering this -- presumably its an EKS-specific kubernetes modification -- helm or kubectl can't create AWS infrastructure by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Helm to deploy a k8s cluster onto AWS EKS

Note: You don't use Helm to deploy a cluster, you use it to deploy applications/workloads/resources to a Kubernetes cluster.

> I want to learn more about this behavior between re deploying k8s resources onto an existing resources and ELB re-creation.

There shouldn't be a recreation of a new ELB/NLB/ALB on redeploying a helm chart if the LoadBalancer services are unmodified if you are using `helm upgrade ...`

The only reason why the load balancers could be recreated is if you are using something like `helm install --replace` or if you are deleting the helm chart in the cluster (`helm delete ...`) and all the ELB/NLB/ALB resources are not being deleted (*maybe an operator created them? or there was failure call the AWS API?*) and then you run again a `helm install`.

Keep in mind that the standard convention for changes in a cluster is to use `helm upgrade` if you are changing any values. If you run `helm install` on top of an existing chart with the same name you should get an error (without the `--replace` option)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I just edited the `helm` command I used. It's `helm upgrade --install --force...`, not `helm install...`. Also, thanks for correcting me about wording as in "You don't use Helm to deploy a cluster, you use it to deploy applications/workloads/resources to a Kubernetes cluster"